# Jquery Ajax HTML5 History Issue - Back button doesn't work for original page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, popstate

I've written a jquery navigation script that replaces content within a div using `.load`. I'm also using the HTML5 History API with pushstate and popstate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.menu_top').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#loading").show();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState({url: href}, '', href);
    $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut('normal').hide().load(href + " #contentwrapper > *");
    $('#contentwrapper').waitForImages(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');  
});

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $("#loading").delay(1000).fadeOut();
});

});
    var popped = ('state' in window.history), initialURL = location.href;
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(event){
    var initialPop = !popped && location.href == initialURL;
    popped = true;
    if ( initialPop ) return;
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;

    $('#contentwrapper').load(state.url + " #contentwrapper > *");
});

});
```

The code mostly works, and the browser's back and forward buttons function normally, UNTIL you try to hit "back" on the browser to go to the original page visited. For example:

Start on page 1

Click link to page 2 - works

Click link to page 3 - works

Hit "back" for page 2 - works

Hit "back" for page 1 - DOESN'T WORK

...

Console gives the following message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null`

This is my first experience with `popstate`. How can I get the browser to navigate back to the original page? I hope I explained the issue well enough. Any help would be appreciated!

[Here's a live demo of the issue, if you care to see it in action.](http://www.fueledbykyle.com/sites/mwood/contact.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as above and below changes worked for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var initialURL;
    var popped = (window.history.state != null), initialURL = location.href;

    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var counter =0;
     var everPushedSomething = false;

     var initialLoad= document.getElementById('hdninitload').value;

     var onloadPop = !everPushedSomething && location.href == initialURL ;

    if(onloadPop){counter = 1;}
    if(initialLoad == 'true'){counter = counter + 1;}


      everPushedSomething = true;
     if (counter != 2) { window.open(location.href, '_self'); }

     }  


    })(window);


    </script>


    <input id="hdninitload" type="hidden" value="true" />

    and Whenever I call history.PushState method,  set this hdninitialload control value to false. something like below:

    history.PushState('','title of the Page','/newPage.aspx'); document.getElementById('hdninitload').value = 'false';

    Hope this works for you as well.
```